# How to SUM and Subtract from different table columns in MSACCESS

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have three tables named: Student, StudentPayment and CreditAmount. I want to show the result that how much a student owe to the school. In student table there is a column named TotalPayable which is the total amount to be paid to the school and in StudentPayment there is a column named TotalPaid which is the total payment each time he made and in the CreditAmount table there is a column named CreditAmount which is the waiver amount which the school gives to the student. So I made a query :

```
SELECT Student.TotalPayableAmount - 
       Sum(StudentPayment.TotalPaid, CreditAmount.WaiverAmount) AS Total_Due
  FROM (Student INNER JOIN StudentPayment ON Student.ID = StudentPayment.ID) 
 INNER JOIN CreditAmount ON (Student.ID = CreditAmount.ID) AND (Student.ID = CreditAmount.StudentID)
 GROUP BY Student.ID, Student.TotalPayableAmount, CreditAmount.WaiverAmount
```

but it shows error.

Actually I want to make the SUM of TotalPaid and CreditAmount and then want to subtract it from the TotalPayable from the student table. Can anyone help me on this please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A `join` repeats each row on the left side for each row on the right side.  So a student with two payments and three credits would end up with 6 rows.  If you `sum` over that, you'd get the wrong result.

Instead, you can use a subquery to calculate the total amounts per student.  Since the subqueries return only one row per student, you avoid the row duplication problem mentioned above.  For example;

```
select  Student.ID
,       Student.TotalPayableAmount - 
        iif(StudentPayment.TotalPaid is null, 0, StudentPayment.TotalPaid) -
        iif(CreditAmount.WaiverAmount is null, 0, CreditAmount.WaiverAmount)
from    (
        Student
        left join    
                (
                select  StudentID
                ,       sum(Paid) as TotalPaid
                from    StudentPayment
                group by
                        StudentID
                ) as StudentPayment
        on    StudentPayment.StudentID = Student.ID
        )
left join    
        (
        select  StudentID
        ,       sum(Waiver) as WaiverAmount
        from    CreditAmount
        group by
                StudentID
        ) as CreditAmount
on      CreditAmount.StudentID = Student.ID
```

Comment: There is no ISNULL function in Access that takes an additional argument to return for `null` values. Use `Nz` instead, or if `Nz` is not available, use `Iif(IsNull(StudentPayment.TotalPaid), 0, StudentPayment.TotalPaid)`

Comment: Also, if any student doesn't have a corresponding total in one of the subqueries, that student will not appear in the resulting query. Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Good points, updated in answer.  I missed the MS-Access part (it's only in the title)

Comment: My database is MS ACCESS database. While I'm trying to run this above code then its showing an error "Syntax error in FROM clause" what can I do for it?

Comment: You need to add some parentheses. Jet SQL requires each join to be wrapped with its own parenthese. `(t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.f1 = t2.f2) INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: This version works for me.  Double check the column names, like `Waiver` and `Paid` ?

Comment: This is working for me also..but actually I'm trying to produce a report where it shows the result in a gridview but in this query it is asking for the parameter as studentID, Paid and Waiver what to do with this? How can I make this to take these parameter direct from the database?

Comment: Fix the column names to what they are in the real tables.  If "CreditAmount" has an ID but not a StudentID column, change that in the query.  Same for Paid and Waiver.

Comment: The confusion over Access vs SQL Server IsNull() has me wondering why bother with IsNull() at all here?  It's not needed: `iif(StudentPayment.TotalPaid Is Null, 0, StudentPayment.TotalPaid)`

Comment: @HansUp Is it more efficient to use the `Is Null` **operator** as opposed to using the `IsNull` **function**? Or is it just for stylistic considerations?

Comment: @ZevSpitz In the past I've seen claims that `Is Null` should be faster  because the db engine does not have to use an additional function.  However, I've never tested, so won't claim a performance benefit large enough to matter, or even any benefit at all.  OTOH, I can't imagine `Is Null` would be *slower* than the function.  So, for me, the decision is based on: `IsNull()` not required and provides no benefit, so don't use it here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the sum of each table individually, then join them by the student ID.

```
SELECT Student.TotalPayableAmount - Nz(sumTotalPaid,0) - Nz(sumCreditAmount,0)
FROM (Student
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Sum(TotalPaid) AS sumTotalPaid
    FROM StudentPayment
    GROUP BY StudentPayment.ID
) AS sum1
    ON Student.ID = sum1.ID)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Sum(CreditAmount) AS sumCreditAmount
    FROM CreditAmount
    GROUP BY CreditAmount.ID
) AS sum2
    ON Student.ID = sum2.ID
```

Note: If you are doing this from an external connection (DAO, ADO, ADO.NET) you won't be able to use the `Nz` function.

Comment: yes I'm using ADO.NET Access data source. Then what should I use instead of NZ?

Comment: `Iif(IsNull(sum1.ID), 0, sum1.ID)` and `Iif(IsNull(sum2.ID), 0, sum2.ID)`

Comment: `Nz(sum1.ID)` should probably be `Nz(sum1.TheSum)`, and the `TheSum` should be added as alias inside the subquery

Comment: @Andomar Fixed in the post, thanks. @barsan - My previous comment was mistaken. Use this: `Iif(IsNull(sumTotalPaid), 0, sumTotalPaid)` and `Iif(IsNull(sumCreditAmount), 0, sumCreditAmount)`